# Inserting new line in sequence manner

Tags: bash, shell

I have a question about inserting a new line in a big text.file by bash scripting;

My file;

```
E.coli.1    gi|1035701777|ref|WP_064543348.1|   85.62   160 23  0   12  171 1   160 4,00E-103   300
E.coli.2    gi|1035701777|ref|WP_064543348.1|   85.62   160 23  0   1   160 1   160 3,00E-103   300
E.coli.5    gi|1036669825|ref|WP_064721309.1|   96.69   393 13  0   2   394 1   393 0.0 748
E.coli.6    gi|1036669825|ref|WP_064721309.1|   96.69   393 13  0   2   394 1   393 0.0 748
E.coli.7    gi|1037427804|ref|WP_064741043.1|   67.95   78  25  0   1   78  1   78  9,00E-33    114
```

My expected output:

```
E.coli.1    gi|1035701777|ref|WP_064543348.1|   85.62   160 23  0   12  171 1   160 4,00E-103   300
E.coli.2    gi|1035701777|ref|WP_064543348.1|   85.62   160 23  0   1   160 1   160 3,00E-103   300
E.coli.3
E.coli.4
E.coli.5    gi|1036669825|ref|WP_064721309.1|   96.69   393 13  0   2   394 1   393 0.0 748
E.coli.6    gi|1036669825|ref|WP_064721309.1|   96.69   393 13  0   2   394 1   393 0.0 748
E.coli.7    gi|1037427804|ref|WP_064741043.1|   67.95   78  25  0   1   78  1   78  9,00E-33    114
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem with not-so-clear description, you can solve it using `awk`:

```
awk -F '[.[:blank:]]+' 'p{for (;p<$3; p++) print f p} NF>3{p=$3+1; f=$1 "." $2 "."}1' file

E.coli.1    gi|1035701777|ref|WP_064543348.1|   85.62   160 23  0   12  171 1   160 4,00E-103   300
E.coli.2    gi|1035701777|ref|WP_064543348.1|   85.62   160 23  0   1   160 1   160 3,00E-103   300
E.coli.3
E.coli.4
E.coli.5    gi|1036669825|ref|WP_064721309.1|   96.69   393 13  0   2   394 1   393 0.0 748
E.coli.6    gi|1036669825|ref|WP_064721309.1|   96.69   393 13  0   2   394 1   393 0.0 748
E.coli.7    gi|1037427804|ref|WP_064741043.1|   67.95   78  25  0   1   78  1   78  9,00E-33    114
```

Comment: Thank you so much anubhava, this script perfectly has solved my problem !